# How to detect too many messages? [Akka Actors]

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

Any actor can get too much messages. How to detect such bottleneck?

If it happen then how would look like the CPU usage? Would there be always at least 1 core on 100% usage or not?

In Akka 1.x I could check length of message queue but is it unavailable in 2.x. How to deal with it now?

Comment: This discussion may be related to your question : http://letitcrash.com/post/17707262394/why-no-mailboxsize-in-akka-2

Comment: Take a look at Kamon.io. It´s easy to configure with Akka. With the LogReporter enabled you can see this metrics related to actors in a easy way

Comment: Can you define "too much" messages?  Usually Actor utilization is a good thing...  What are you ultimately looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too many messages in an actor do not cause any cpu issues - they would eventually consume a lot of memory depending on the messages and the used strategy. Have a look at these strategies: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.16/scala/mailboxes.html The default is an unbounded mailbox - so the system would eat up all the memory... (consider using backpressure for such cases - see akka streams)

Kamon allows you to see the actors metrics (mailbox size etc).
This is quite simple to configure (but needs aspectj)
http://kamon.io/integrations/akka/actor-router-and-dispatcher-metrics/